Is South Korea's opposition planning to normalize relations with North Korea?
South Korea's President Yoon Suk Yeol surprisingly issued a decree enacting martial law in the country which was quickly reversed by his cabinet. The opposition Democratic Party said it would begin impeachment proceedings against Yoon if he refused to step down immediately.
President Yoon said:

To safeguard a liberal South Korea from the threats posed by North Korea’s communist forces and to eliminate anti-state elements… I hereby declare emergency martial law,”

Do the recent events in South Korea imply that the opposition party had been planning to normalize relations with North Korea after getting ahold of power that could pose a threat to the United States which maintains military bases there and is actively fighting the nuclear threat of North Korea?
Is there intelligence indicating that, or did the South Korean president act on suspicions and irregular behavior by the opposition?

There is a big difference between not wanting to declare martial law and wanting to normalize relations with a country that they are still in a state of war with even though the active conflict has died down.

@JoeW and also they keep claiming that they are both parts of the same country

"Treachery!  They want to sell us to Kim Jong Un!" has a much nicer ring than "Stop investigating my wife for bribery!", does it not?  But, yes, this a bona fide question.  An attempted coup is a big deal, claims were made to justify it and its reasonable to ask if there are any grounds for those claims.  Note that while relations have deteriorated since Yoon took over in 2022, they have been on downward slide for a while https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaesong_Industrial_Region so Yoon's and his opponents attitudes dont matter as much as the North's tantrums.

Voting to close - The title and actual question asked are quite different. Please clarify and improve your question.

There are way too many questions in there. While the US are certainly part of the landscape, how do they fit into this question? It sounds like a conspiracy theory as in “the US forced him to declare martial law to protect their interests against communists”.

The general belief, at least at this moment in time, is that Yoon's declaration of martial law had absolutely nothing to do with North Korea at all.
To put this whole situation into some context: Yoon Suk Yeol has been deeply unpopular since he entered office in 2022. His administration has been hit with a series of scandals, most prominently when his wife was alleged to have accepted a Dior handbag from a church pastor. Per the BBC, his approval ratings had fallen to as low as 17% prior to the martial law declaration.
In April, the opposing Democratic Party won a landslide victory in the parliamentary elections, gaining a 20-seat majority in the National Assembly. This left Yoon as a "lame duck" president, unable to pass any legislation of his own and having to veto any legislation passed by the Democrat-controlled Assembly that he objected to (which was most of it).
Again as per the BBC, politically-motivated prosecutions are also fairly common in South Korea. At least two former presidents have been jailed for corruption, and a third committed suicide while being investigated on similar charges. The belief, therefore, is that Yoon knew he would lose the next election and feared being prosecuted in a similar manner, therefore he attempted a desperate power-grab by declaring martial law. His mentions of "North Korea’s communist forces" and "anti-state elements" appear to be nothing more than classic Red Scare tactics, used in a flimsy attempt to justify his actions.
It's worth noting that Yoon's predecessor, Moon Jae-in, was a Democrat, and that relations with North Korea thawed significantly under his rule (though not to the extent of "normalization") before decaying to their worst state in decades under Yoon's rule.

Thanks for this answer. Btw. when are the next presidential elections scheduled in South Korea? And who actually does decide foreign policy (relations with North Korea) in South Korea, the National Assembly or the president/the government?

@NoDataDumpNoContribution It's a five-year term, so the next presidential election is scheduled for 2027.As for who decides foreign policy, I don't know, but the National Assembly do seem to have the power to decide which bills end up on the president's desk.

The "most prominent" scandal was his wife accepting a gift handbag?!  I guess the standards are a bit different there than in the US...

@MichaelHall Not really, this answer glosses over a lot of other problems. One is post-COVID inflation, which affected incumbents globally. Another is the South Korean doctor's strike, which is approaching a year.

About those "communist forces" and "anti-state elements" - being raised up in a communist country, I have to notice that this is the exact same method they used to dismantle the small forms of internal opposition (more moderate branches of the Party) which were available until they made the regime much stricter: by claiming that they are capitalist-imperialist agents and are plotting to sell the country to the imperialists.

@vsz To clarify, should we understand by your comment that you think Pres. Yoon is full of horse manure?  That's the way I interpret it.

@MichaelHall My understanding is that many Asian countries are indeed substantially less blunted to the idea of political corruption than we in the West. When I was in Singapore I got told that the best way for a politician to go to jail is to accept any gift or donation that could be construed as bribery.

@xLeitix As if Singapore is representative of "many Asian countries" in legal system, governance, size, wealth, public service competency... and bribery tolerance.
